# I have a hard time trying to understand this

Tags: python

```
m = 0
x = 1
while x < 4:
    y = 1
    while y < 3:
        m = m + x + y
        y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
print(m)
```

The output is supposed to be 21 but i dont get it , what am i missing?  a little help please

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "i dont get it".

Comment: add a couple of `print()` for each assignment and look at the output to trace the flow of the program

Comment: I ran the code and the output is 21! what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `m = 0` and `x = 1`
2. Since `x < 4` it goes inside the `while` loop where `y` is set to `1`
3. Since `y < 3` it goes inside the nested `while`
4. `m` becomes `m + x + y = 0 + 1 + 1 = 2` and `y` becomes `y + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2`
5. Back to the loop condition: `y < 3`? Yes! Because `y = 2`. So it goes again inside the `while`
6. `m` becomes `m + x + y = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5` and `y` becomes `3`
7. Back again to the loop condition: `y < 3`? No! `3` is not less than `3`, so the `while` is now skipped
8. `x` becomes `x + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2`
9. Back to first `while` condition: `x < 4`? Yes! Because `x = 2`. So it goes inside the loop again
10. Back to step **2**.
11. When `x` finally becomes `4`, the `while` loop will terminate and `m` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a "graphical" representation.
Consider:

- *x* values starting with 1 and growing from left to right (we don't care what's after 3: `while x < 4`)
- *y* values (**!!! for each *x* !!!**) starting with 1 and growing from top to bottom (we don't care what's after 2: `while y < 3`)
- *x* values are displayed using the "normal" font style, while *y* ones are displayed in "*italic*"
- Everything that we care about is displayed in "**bold**" (actually what is not in "**bold**" won't even be computed by the program, I'm placing those values here, just for clarity's sake):

  - *x* values (*x* ∈ {1, 2, 3})
  - *y* values (*y* ∈ {1, 2})
- *x* row is displayed twice, since for each *y*, *x* is added to the sum
- The sum:

  - Is under the separation line and starts from 0
  - Each number is the sum (consider it a partial sum) of the numbers (in **bold**) on that column (above it) - they correspond to **one** *x* iteration and they contain **all** *y* iterations for that *x*
  - At the end, we add those values - for **all** *x* iterations - and get the final value

**x** (→):        **1**     **2**     **3**     4     5     6     *...*
***y*** (↓):          ***1***     ***1***     ***1***     *1*    *...*
**x** (→):        **1**     **2**     **3**     4     5     6     *...*
***y*** (↓):          ***2***     ***2***     ***2***     *2*    *...*
*y* (↓):          *3*     *3*     *3*     *3*    *...*
*y* (↓):          *...*   *...*    *...*    *...*    *...*

---

**sum**:    **0** +  **5**  + **7** + **9**      **=**     **21**